# jquery-ui-sortable not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

Currently I have a sortable card container where the user can drag the cards and place them in any position they want to. I am using `jquery.ui.widget.js` library to do this. The following is the code in my AJAX to achieve this.

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
            cursor: 'move',
            start: function(event, ui) {
                ui.item.addClass('grabbing moving').removeClass('col-sm-6');
                ui.placeholder
                    .addClass('starting')
                    .removeClass('moving')
                    .css({
                        top: ui.originalPosition.top,
                        left: ui.originalPosition.left
                    });
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {
                ui.placeholder.removeClass('starting');
            },
            update: function(event, ui) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo site_url('listings/sortlisimages/' . $this->uri->segment(3)); ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: $(this).sortable('serialize'),
                    success: function(data) {}
                });
            },
            beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
                ui.placeholder.after(ui.item);
            }
        });
```

Now this is working in all the browsers I tested with except for FireFox. I'm basically trying this out: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ and this example works in firefox for their official website so it's not a compatibality issue, yet for mine it does not work on firefox, not sure why. Also there are no errors in my console.

Comment: Why don't you put some full example of the code including HTML structure? I've tried your piece of code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Bokovinsky/pen/XWeWXLx) and it works perfectly for Firefox (v94.0.2). I've only removed `ajax` request from your sample because it was throwing an error.

Comment: Seems the problem is in your request. To be more exact - with PHP code injection. Are you sure that it is correct? Also injecting PHP code into JS is not good practice especially when you are just leaving it as it is here for review.